# Measuring the symmetry of a set in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, symmetry

Suppose is given a finite set of positions in $\mathbb{R}^d$. And a finite group $G$. Is there any way to measure the symmetry of the set related to G?
For example if the set consist of vertices of a square it is clear that is symmetric to the dihedral group of eight elements. While if the set has vertices of a rhombus is *partially* symmetric because there are some elements of $G$ that preserve the positions. And a scalene triangle do not have any symmetry for this group. There is some way to measure that?
I am interested at any reference on this.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the question is asking. Are you just asking how to compute the subgroup of the given group $G$ that preserves (under the specified action $G \times \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$) the configuration $X$ of points? In that case, why can't you just compute the configurations $g \cdot X$ for each $g \in G$ and toss out the $g$ that don't give you $X$ back?

Comment: No. It is more in the sense of measure theory. But I am not sure to how to formulate that. One attempt would be: There exist some meausure $\mu_G:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow R^+$ such that $\mu_G(A)>\mu_G(B)$ implies that $A$ is _more_ symmetric than $B$?   In the cases that I mentioned $\mu_{D_{8}}(square)>\mu_{D_{8}}(rhombus)>\mu_{D_{8}}(scalene triangle)$.

Comment: The idea that you I think you want depends both on the action $G \times \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$ *and* the embedding $X \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^d$ of each of the shapes. For example, the standard action of $D_8$ on $\Bbb R^2$ fixes some squares but not others. Once you've fixed these, you can ask for the size of the stabilizer $\operatorname{Stab}_G(X)$ of $X$ in $G$, that is the number of elements in $G$ that fix $X$. This size is just the counting measure on the size of the stabilizer, but it's not clear to me that thinking about this measure-theoretically (rather than just a count) is useful.

Comment: (Incidentally, a measure on $\Bbb R^d$ is a function from a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^d$ to $[0, +\infty]$.)

Comment: By the way, there are configurations $X, Y, Z$ such that the standard action of $G = D_{12}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ fixes $X$ (say, a regular hexagon centered on the origin and preserved by any reflection), the stabilizer of $Y$ is $D_6 \cong S_3$ (e.g., an equilateral triangle formed by every other vertex of $X$) and the stabilizer of $Z$ is $C_6$. Then, the stabilizers of $Y$ and $Z$ in $G$ both have $6$ elements, but $Y \neq Z$ and in particular neither stabilizer fixes the other configuration. In this scenario do you want $Y$ and $Z$ to have equal "symmetry", or do you want them to be incomparable?

Comment: In this scenario I want Y and Z to have equal "symmetry". It seems that  the size of stabilizer is a natural of thinking. I want something where all configurations could be comparable. But I do not know if this is possible. Thanks.